# Run specific unit test according to condition

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have a test class containing test cases for say blue and non-blue devices. If the parameter isBlue is set then it should run only those test case that have say the @Blue annotation. I am not sure how to implement this specific annotation that will achieve this functionality.

```
public class TestClass {

   boolean isBlue = false;

   @Before
   public void setUp () {
      isBlue = MyApplication.instance().isBlue();
   }

   @Test
   public void testA () { ... }

   @Test @Blue
   public void testB() { ... }
}
```

In this example if `isBlue` is `true` then it should only run `testB()` otherwise it should run all test cases

Comment: I haven't used them, but this might be a use-case for JUnit [categories](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/categories).  You might also just solve this with inheritance.

Comment: Even though there are some approaches that could be helpful here, I think that your test should be split in two - a test for blue devices, and a test for non-blue devices. And you should probably trigger the usage of Mock objects, with which you could simulate behavior/properties of your objects (like `MyApplication`)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at JUnit runners. [Nice explanation of runners](http://www.mscharhag.com/java/understanding-junits-runner-architecture)

You can create your own runner which will extend on `BlockJUnit4ClassRunner`.

You can override

```
@Override
  protected List<FrameworkMethod> getChildren() {
    // scan test class for methonds annotated with @Test
  }
```

To additionally filter by methods that have your custom annotation set, and your property in the application is set as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the wrong path.

You want your test cases to help identifying problems; and assist you in **fixing** them. Anything that "distracts" you from that purpose reduces the values of your unit tests.

Thus: don't put tests that have really "different" scope into the same test class. Especially from the point of view: how would you control what "MyApplication.instance()" would return? That sounds like a problem in itself.

Meaning: you want to have two independent tests; and those don't rely on some "static" object telling them something. They test what is in their scope; nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

By using jUnit [Assume](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assume.html)

```
@Test
public void testA () { 
    assumeTrue(MyApplication.instance().isBlue());
    ... 
}
```

> [A failing assumption in a @Before or @BeforeClass method will have the same effect as a failing assumption in each @Test method of the class.](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/assumptions-with-assume)